# Qt: is it OK to do long job in the other thread's event loop

Tags: multithreading, qt

I need to implement a form with buttons and log widget, and when button is pressed, some long job should start in the other thread.

Details of the process should be echoed to the log.

Two jobs should not be started simultaneously.

The way I'm thinking about: create subclass of `QThread` with its own event loop (of course call `moveToThread(this)` in the `QThread`'s constructor), and connect signal of `QButton` to the slot `doLongJob()` of this thread.

Does it sound good, or is it generally wrong? Other way: say, create new thread every time user pressed button. Seems to be worse.

Is there some best practices to do this pretty common thing? Please give me a suggestion.

Comment: You generally [do not want to subclass QThread](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/), but other than that, hooking up things with signals and slots is just fine.

Comment: @Bart, great thanks for opening my eyes on how to use QThread properly. I'm pretty surprized how so well-formed framework as Qt might have so misleading docs. And, really, I have seen many examples with subclasses of QThread..

Comment: Subclassing `QThread` isn't the end of the world, but the memory management is harder, and there are a lot of gotchas mixed in that you have to be aware of.

Comment: @Bart, I already did it as it is explained in the article, so, please write your comment as answer, and I'll accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Bart, really, please write your comment about not to subclassing `QThread` as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bard already answered in the comment, I asked him twice to write the same as an answer, but it seems he really doesn't want to.

So, I'm tired of waiting more than 7 months, and therefore have to do that myself, in order to get rid of this unanswered question.

The answer is:

*You generally [do not want to subclass QThread](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/), but other than that, hooking up things with signals and slots is just fine.*